# Can't use text listner on EditText

Tags: android

I'm trying to hide an `TextView` when it's related `EditText` is empty. To check if it is empty i want to use an `TextChangedListner` as i saw in other posts, but somehow i don't have that option. When i use `addTextChangedListner` i get an warrning that `Cannot resolve symbol 'addTextChangedListen'`.

I included `EditText` and `TextView` aswell.

```
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Register extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
    }

    //first name
    EditText firstnameBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.firstnameText);
    firstnameBox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged() {
            //here i'm going to see if the firstnameBox is empty or not
            ...
        }
    });
}
```

How can i use the Text Changed Listner ?

Comment: Your `EditText` cast and `TextWatcher` should be inside of `onCreate` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the below lines inside the `OnCreate` method after `setContentView`

```
    //first name
EditText firstnameBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.firstnameText);
firstnameBox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged() {
        //here i'm going to see if the firstnameBox is empty or not
        ...
    }
});
```

Comment: So it can be use only in the `OnCreate` method ?

Comment: In this case yes because you need to initialise your EditText before you try to add a listener to it.

Answer (score 0):

You must write your code in executable manner..

Write your `editText.addTextChangeListener` code into `onCreate()` method.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

   EditText firstnameBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.firstnameText);
   firstnameBox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged() {
            //here i'm going to see if the firstnameBox is empty or not
            ...
        }
    });
}
```

For more info check out this [Android Activity LifeCycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html)